# Predicate logic a game where player goes first?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

What kind of predicate logic statement describes a game that the person who goes first can always win? Write you answer in terms of successive moves by two players.

I am lost here I tried initially showing strategies used to win win1 and win2 and then each move of player 1 and 2 as r1 and r2.

8x9y(R1xy^Win1(y)!Win1(x) 
where r1 reaches bottom state must have 8 moves to reach bottom state.

Help please I think I may not be making sense

Comment: It is a little confusing.  You need a notion of a state of a game and the notion of a move allowed that will change that state (the Board and its Moves, for lack of a more precisely term).  Some moves are immediately winning as the game transitions to a final state where the mover has won.  So capturing those immediate wins is part of the predicate of winning, essentially the "basis case" of a recursive definition.  The "induction case" is for those moves that leave the game in a state where the opposing player has no winning move.  So this part of the definition needs a quantifier.

Comment: how do I write this in successive moves by players? I understand that this is first player win theory correct? But I do not understand how this would be written?

Comment: It's hard to tell where you are coming from, in posting this Question.  Do you have a background in formal logic?  Is this an exercise you want help with?  As I tried to outline, you've jumped to the end of the exercise when there is some preliminary setup work (context) that needs to be supplied.  Trivially there is the Charlie Sheen approach: just cry "Winning!" and claim that represents the idea of the first player always wins.